# Summer '14 Developer Console fails to load?

Tags: developer-console, bug, summer14

Using Google Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 m on Windows 7 Enterprise 64-Bit, using two different sandboxes on CS10, the Developer Console refuses to load, instead just showing a blank screen. Inspecting the console using F12 reveals the following errors:

```
* Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Queued' of undefined cs10.salesforce.com/jslibrary/1404422836000/sfdc/main.js:1015
* Uncaught Error: Ext.Loader is not enabled, so dependencies cannot be resolved dynamically. Missing required class: apex.ide.ViewerPerspectiveDefinition cs10.salesforce.com/EXT/ext-4.1.0/ext-all.js:18
* Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'IDE' of undefined cs10.salesforce.com/jslibrary/1402438808000/sfdc/ApexIDETop_Ext4.js:6
```

The console works fine in IE 10 running in IE 7 Standards mode (?!). Other instances we have access to, such as CS11, and CS18, both in Summer '14, do not exhibit this behavior. Is this a known issue, and is there a fix?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 64 bit and also have Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 m.  I'm able to load the Developer Console.  Are those javascript libraries something everyone would be loading?

Comment: @Jagular Did you try on CS10? All other instances are working correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the CS10 part.  I'm on CS2 for sandboxes and whatever the production environment is that doesn't have any additional distinguishing letters/numbers.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on cs8.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on the developer forum:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000AXggIAG

1. The current stable version of chrome is 35.0.1916.114 m. Make sure your version and Update your chrome .
2. Don't use beta version Browser.
3. Clear cookies and browser settting, If the issue still persistent reinstall the chrome

*Clearing cache and cookies worked for me.

Comment: I'm going to try clearing the cache in the morning, since it's on my work computer. The post is technically outdated; I'm on the default Google Chrome installation, which auto-updates to the latest stable version automatically, but not Canary or anything advanced.